# How to build reactjs application in gitlab pipeline?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm in the middle of setting up a CI/CD pipeline using GitLab.

In the pipeline, the final step, is building the project and store it as artifact due to be downloaded from another automated process.

Everything is ok, until I "copy" (automation or not) the build/ directory in prod.

Blank page with an error: [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=undefined&args%5B%5D=)

Using `npm run build` on my machine, and publishing these files everything is ok.

Both versions are identical:
node: 16.15.0
npm: 8.10.0

Am i missing something?
I can add more details but i don't know what you need.

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - preparation
  - building


image: node:16.15.0-alpine3.15

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"

npm:
  stage: preparation
  before_script:
    - npm install -g npm@latest
  script:
    - npm -v
    - npm install --no-optional --legacy-peer-deps
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/


build-assets:
  stage: building
  # Download the artifacts for these jobs
  dependencies:
    - npm
  before_script:
    - npm install -g npm@latest
  script:
    - npm --version
    - node --version
    - unset NODE_OPTIONS
    - CI=false npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/static/css
      - build/static/js
      - build/static/media
      - build/static/img
      - build/asset-manifest.json
      - build/manifest.json
      - build/index.html
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always
```

Comment: Can you please share your .gitlab-ci.yaml?

Comment: @ManojKumar added content of file

Comment: Your `npm` stage is of no use as you are doing same thing again in build stage.

Comment: Are you using it only for building assets or also for deployment ?

Comment: @ManojKumar i found the issue: for some reason i wan't pushing package-lock.json and the pipeline downloaded the last version of a libray. THanks for your support anyway